# How do you make the size of an image and texts smaller but still making it side-by-side?

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML and CSS:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    background: radial-gradient(#484646, #212020);
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    display: flex;
}

.product-info {
    background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.4);
}

.product-info h2 {
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
}

.product-info p {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container">
        <div class = "product-img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200.png" alt = "Image">
        </div>
        <div class = "product-info">
            <h2>Product name</h2>
            <p>Description: Product description</p>
            <p>Price: $2000</p>
            <p>Color: Black</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

In my browser, the image and the texts look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u44YW.jpg) which appears very huge but I want to make them look smaller instead. Is there a way to go about with this?

Comment: Please explain a little more mentioning what you have tried, what is you goal and what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set the *width & height* of the `div.product-img` to 200x200. And then set the width and height of the image to 100% (both). That means even if your image is 1920x1080, it will fit its parent completely.
2. You're using `max-width: 1200px;`. This means the container will increase the width until it reaches 1200px and then it will not increase anymore. Instead of using *max-width*, I recommend you using only `width` so it won't increase the width as much as possible.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  background: radial-gradient(#484646, #212020);
}

.container {
  /* EDITED HERE */
  /* max-width: 1200px; */
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
}

/* ADDED HERE PART1 */
.product-img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

/* ADDED HERE PART2 */
.product-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.product-info {
  background-color: rgba(28, 28, 28, 0.4);
}

.product-info h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.product-info p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="product-img">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="Image">
  </div>
  <div class="product-info">
    <h2>Product name</h2>
    <p>Description: Product description</p>
    <p>Price: $2000</p>
    <p>Color: Black</p>
  </div>
</div>
```